# Can I invoke 'make' from kate?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kate, make

In vim I can invoke ':make', which starts make, and if there are errors, it opens the file at the line where the error was. Is there something similar in kate? I've found a 'Focus Terminal' command, but it just opens a terminal, and I am specifically looking for the feature where the text editor goes to the lines where there are errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the answer is NO.

As you already found out, there is a terminal plug-in, from which you can invoke the make (and that is what I do).

---

Aparently, they added the [build plugin](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-baseapps/kate/kate-application-plugin-build.html) for kate.

Comment: @satuon They added a build plug in recently. Edited the answer with link